# Save trained model in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am follorwing this tutorial to create a classifier
[Tutorial Link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/use-keras-deep-learning-models-scikit-learn-python/)

`

```
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset with grid search via sklearn
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    import numpy

    # Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
    def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='sigmoid'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    seed = 7
    numpy.random.seed(seed)
    # load pima indians dataset
    dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
    # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
    X = dataset[:,0:8]
    Y = dataset[:,8]
    # create model
    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
    # grid search epochs, batch size and optimizer
    optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
    init = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform']
    epochs = [50, 100, 150]
    batches = [5, 10, 20]
    param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=init)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
    # summarize results
    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

The code works fine, I wish to save the trained model to an external file, please guide me.

I know about keras model.save to save a model, but here we have done some external work on the model, how do I save the model with all changes?

Comment: did you try pickle it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `model.fit()`, you have to include a callback. The callback will save the model on a file using `ModelCheckpoint`. After training, you can load the model back using Keras `load_model`.

```
   epochs = 10 
   batch_size = 64
   filepath = "checkpoint/model.{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
   checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, verbose=1,\ 
         save_best_only=False)
   callbacks = [checkpoint]
   model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs,\ 
         batch_size=batch_size,\
         shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks)
```